# Where to add custom configuration for external libraries(npm modules) in react

Tags: reactjs, axios

Where to add custom configuration for external libraries(npm modules) in react, which will be used in entire app

My problem statement is:
I am doing api calls using axios, i don't want to include authentication header in each call separately, i am thinking to create a file and import axios there and do something like this

```
customAxios = axios
customAxios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = store.getState().session.token;

export customAxios
```

Now i will import customAxios in any file where i need to do api call
Is this the correct way? if it's not how to handle this situation

Btw i am new to react

Comment: You could use encrypted cookies or local storage to store auth header and look it up when you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an api class in whose constructor you can create an axios instance and assign the header information. Then use the instance in all your calls.

```
export default class Api{    
    constructor(auth_token){
        this.customAxios= axios.create({
            baseURL: 'https://myserverurl.com'
          });              
          this.customAxios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = auth_token;            
    }

    getInfo(){
        this.customAxios.get('/info') ....// do further processing and return data
    }
}
```

And when you want to call the api you can create an instance and use that instance for your calls.

```
let apiInstance = new Api(store.getState().session.token);
apiInstance.getInfo();
```